# Finding the accuracy of an accelerometer

Tags: acceleration

I would like to measure and compare the accuracy of different accelerometers.

Obviously I must choose a reference, therefore I compare all the accelerometer with this reference and then decide which is the most precise.

How can I select this reference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in two distinct ways:

1) use a reference (I'll give an example below)

2) measure other quantities that can be converted into an acceleration.

Here are some possibilities:

1a) Gravity. At rest, the accelerometer should measure the local g.

2a) Put it on a rotating platform. Knowing the rotational speed and distance to the pivot, you can calculate the acceleration.

2b) Put in on a swing

2c) Shoot it with a catapult

2d) Put it on a subwoofer

2e) ...

The list goes on and on. Practical methods depend on the type of accelerometer.